# Check if Unity Build Successfully or Not (UNITY C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here's my script for building Programmatically

```
BuildPlayerOptions szBuildResult = new BuildPlayerOptions();
szBuildResult.scenes = scenes;
szBuildResult.locationPathName = m_szapkFileName;
szBuildResult.target = BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows;
szBuildResult.options = BuildOptions.None;

BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(szBuildResult);
```

Now I tried to do something like this

```
string result = BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(szBuildResult);
```

But it's returning me an error saying

> Cannot convert type UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport to string

How can i check if the build is successful or not?

I'm using Unity 2018.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer.html)  will reutrn  `BuildReport` object. so use `BuildReport` instead of `string`

```
BuildReport result = BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(szBuildResult);
```

Comment: @BoonMingProg No problem glad to help